# .empty() em javascript, como fazer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando um script de preview para imagens criado com jquery, porém quero realizá-lo em Javascript Vanilla, estou procurando uma forma de substituir o comando variávelQualquer.empty(); porém não encontrei, como posso substituir este comando ?

Código em JQuery

```
$("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {

    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
        image_holder.empty();

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("<img />", {
                "src": e.target.result,
                "class": "thumb-image"
            }).appendTo(image_holder);
        }
        image_holder.show();
        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    } else{
        alert("Este navegador não suporta FileReader.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Queres substituir o comando empty(); de jquery por o nativo de js é isso?

Comment: exato mano :D quero saber como ele funciona no vanilla

Comment: acho que `ele.innerHTML = '';` resolve

Comment: pra um input do tipo file ? por exemplo file.innerHTML = null ?

Comment: Queres tirar o ficheiro selecionado do input file é isso? `inputfile.value='';`

Comment: Então, não sei direito qual foi a lógica utilizada pelo cara, mas vou atualizar a pergunta com o código em jquery

Comment: A função `empty` do jQuery exclui todos os elementos filhos do elemento selecionado. Neste caso, estaria excluindo todas os elementos `img` dentro do elemento `#image-holder`. No *vanilla*, o equivalente seria algo como `document.getElementById("image-holder").innerHTML = ''`, tal como o Miguel comentou.

Comment: obrigado, alguém poderia formular uma resposta para dar como concluida ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `.empty()` nesse caso é simplesmente `innerHTML = '';`.

Esse script em JavaScript nativo poderia ser assim:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var image_holder = document.getElementById('image-holder');
input.addEventListener('change', function() {

  if (typeof FileReader != "undefined") {
    image_holder.innerHTML = '';
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = e.target.result;
      img.className = 'thumb-image';
      image_holder.appendChild(img);
    }
    image_holder.style.display = 'block'; // aqui poderá haver outras variantes para mostrar o elemento
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  } else {
    alert('Este navegador não suporta FileReader.');
  }
});
```

Comment: o código todo foi passado para vanilla ?

Comment: @MuriloGambôa exato. O que tinhas na pergunta foi o que eu "converti".

Comment: Agora me sobrou uma dúvida, o seguinte trecho está causando erro `reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);` - `Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.imageFileInput.onchange`

Comment: obg man :) ajudou dms]

Comment: @MuriloGambôa tinha-me falhado esse. `$(this)[0]` é o mesmo que somente `this`. Bem claro quanto o jQuery é desnecessário :D

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do Sergio está correta, mas vou deixar aqui uma alternativa que tem [performance melhor](https://jsperf.com/emptying-a-dom-element/1) – útil caso esteja precisando otimizar sua aplicação.

A função abaixo recebe um elemento do DOM e remove todos os elementos filhos dele, um a um, até que ele esteja vazio:

```
function empty(el) {
    while(el.children.length) {         // enquanto houver filhos
        el.removeChild(el.children[0]); // remove o primeiro filho
    }
}
```